# Passing pointers to members with a variadic template

Tags: c++, c++17

Consider the code below:

```
struct A {int x; bool y; double z;};

template <class T>
void func(T A::*fieldPtr) {}

int main() { func(&A::x); }
```

is it possible to make `func` accept multiple pointers to `A` members with variadic templates? So it can be used as follows:

```
func(&A::x, &A::y);
func(&A::x, &A::y, &A::z);
...
```

My first idea was this:

```
    template <class... Args>
    void func(Args... A::*fieldPtr);
```

but it does not compile.

**EDIT1**

With MSVC 2017 I get: error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition

With Clang: see [live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/N7jOLpQxISD7sPRK).

Comment: Also at least take the effort to format `struct A`'s definition correctly.

Comment: @Barry it is `struct A {int x; bool y; double z;};`

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky _now_ it is.

Comment: @Kyll see EDIT1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to make func accept multiple pointers to A members with variadic templates?
>
> My first idea was this:
>
> ```
>  template <class... Args>
>  void func(Args... A::*fieldPtr);
> ```
>
> but it does not compile.

Try with

```
template <class ... Ts>
void func(Ts A::*...fieldPtr) { /* do something with fieldPtr... */ }
// ..............^^^
```

Comment: Is this a guess or an answer? Is there an explanation of how you came up with this or why it might help?

Comment: It compiles, but I am not sure I understand why :)

Comment: In all pack declaration, the type comes before the `...`, in this example `Ts A::*` is the type in the same way as you would write `T*...` and not `T ...*`.

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky - Rule of thumb: declaring a variadic pack, ever place the ellipsis (the `...`) immediately before the name of the variables/types (`filedPtr`, in this case); unpacking it, place the ellipsis immediately after.